# Xrdp not working in wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

I am installing xfce-4 in wsl ubuntu when i give this command
`sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start`
it is giving:
`Starting xrdp (via systemctl): xrdp.service.`
instead of this:
`Starting xrdp (via systemctl): xrdp.service'`
please help me to fix this
i am new into wsl

Comment: What is the user-visible problem that this is causing?